# Reference dynamic Id in JSF composite components

Tags: jsf, components, composite-component

I've been having some trouble to reference Id with composite components in JSF like the example:

```
`<composite:interface> 
<composite:attribute name="id" required="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>  
<h:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.id}" value="Any" 
</composite:implementation>
```

`
And when I try to pass the Id as param, I can't reference it from a "for" for example from an outputLabel, it seems this kind of composite components in JSF does not support dynamic Ids, what is the solution for it?

Thanks in advance.